# Caps button for an IOS8 custom keyboard extension

Tags: xcode, ios8

When creating a custom keyboard extension for IOS8, what code would I link to the CAPS button? (This is in Objective C)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A BOOL:

```
if (capsEnabled) {
     [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:[letter uppercaseString]];
}
else {
     [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:letter];
}
```